# 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history' Keras with no Tensorflow tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

This code:

```
a = Input(ish)
for i in range(a.shape[1]):
  x=Conv2D(filters=50, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation=rl)(a[:,i])
  x=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(x)
  x=Dropout(0.5)(x)
  x=Conv2D(filters=100, kernel_size=5, padding='same', activation=rl)(x)
  x=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(x)
  x=Dropout(0.5)(x)
  x=Conv2D(filters=200, kernel_size=7, padding='same', activation=rl)(x)
  x=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(x)
t=Flatten()(x)
t=Dropout(0.7)(t)
b=Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(t)

model = Model(inputs=a, outputs=b)
```

in the last line, gives this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'
```

Any idea what cause the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do the indexing inside a Lambda layer, in order to keep the Keras metadata:

```
a = Input(ish)
for i in range(a.shape[1]):
  x=Lambda(lambda x: x[:, i])(a)
  x=Conv2D(filters=50, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation=rl)(x)
  x=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(x)
  x=Dropout(0.5)(x)
  x=Conv2D(filters=100, kernel_size=5, padding='same', activation=rl)(x)
  x=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(x)
  x=Dropout(0.5)(x)
  x=Conv2D(filters=200, kernel_size=7, padding='same', activation=rl)(x)
  x=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(x)
t=Flatten()(x)
t=Dropout(0.7)(t)
b=Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(t)

model = Model(inputs=a, outputs=b)
```